# Nested strings - 3 levels - with quotes

Tags: javascript, quotes

I have this (this is part of the code):

```
<select class="form-select" id="topicId" name="topicId" onchange="javascript:
                var data = $(':input[name]', '#dynamic-form').serialize();
                $.ajax(
                  'ajax.php/form/help-topic/' + this.value,
                  {
                    data: data,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(json) {                            
                        var eng1 = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');
                        eng1[eng1.length-1].style.display = 'none';
                    }
                  });">
```

The problem is `input[type="text"]` - the quotes around the type *text* give me serious problems since the whole section of code already is wrapped inside "".
But how on earth do I solve this?
Any ideas?

Comment: Why would you put entire javascript snippets in `onchange` in the first place?

Comment: This is why inline JS in attributes is such a bad idea. Call a function and you won't have a problem.

Comment: BTW, you don't need `javascript:` in `onXXX` attributes. That's only needed in attributes that contain a URL, such as `href`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to extract the code from the `onchange` attribute into a function, and call the function from the attribute.

```js
function sendAjax() {
  var data = $(':input[name]', '#dynamic-form').serialize();
  $.ajax(
    'ajax.php/form/help-topic/' + this.value, {
      data: data,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(json) {
        var eng1 = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');
        eng1[eng1.length - 1].style.display = 'none';
      }
    });
}
```

```html
<select class="form-select" id="topicId" name="topicId" onchange="sendAjax()">
```

or you can bind the event listener from JS without using `onchange`.

```js
$("#topicId").change(function() {
  var data = $(':input[name]', '#dynamic-form').serialize();
  $.ajax(
    'ajax.php/form/help-topic/' + this.value, {
      data: data,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(json) {
        var eng1 = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');
        eng1[eng1.length - 1].style.display = 'none';
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<select class="form-select" id="topicId" name="topicId">
```

If there's some reason you *must* put all the code in `onchange`, you can use single quotes around the name instead of double quotes. You'll need to escape them because single quotes are being used around the selector.

```
<select class="form-select" id="topicId" name="topicId" onchange="javascript:
                var data = $(':input[name]', '#dynamic-form').serialize();
                $.ajax(
                  'ajax.php/form/help-topic/' + this.value,
                  {
                    data: data,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(json) {                            
                        var eng1 = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=\'text\']');
                        eng1[eng1.length-1].style.display = 'none';
                    }
                  });">
```

Finally, you use simply use `$('input:text:last').hide()`.

Answer (score 0):

i dont understand why not just write all of it inside `<script>`..? but anyway you can change all the single tags ( ' ) to backtags, and then change the global double-tags ( `onchange="..."` ) to single tags.